# Android getting unexpected response from remote server call

Tags: android

I am trying to send a call to a remote server with user credentials, and get back a true/false for whether the persons credentials match. But my code is returning the credentials right back to me in JSON lol

```
        try 
        {               
            String query = String.format("login=%s&password=%s", 
                     URLEncoder.encode(myEmail, charset), 
                     URLEncoder.encode(myPassword, charset));

            final URL url = new URL( myUrl + "?" + query );



            final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true); 
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setRequestProperty("login", myEmail);
            conn.setRequestProperty("password", myPassword);

            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            final InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[8196];
            int readCount;
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((readCount = is.read(buffer)) > -1) 
            {
                builder.append(new String(buffer, 0, readCount));
            }

            response = builder.toString();      
            Log.d( "After call, response: " , " " + response);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
                Log.d( "Exception: " , "Yup");
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Would anyone know how I can get the output from the server instead of this stuff that I get back now?

Thanks!

Comment: check the service in CRest Chrome Browser App.

Comment: @Sadeshkumar Periyasamy what do you mean? How do I do that? :) Thanks!

Comment: It's a Chrome Web Store App to test Rest Web services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly the code you have posted works on my standalone java client as well as in my android app. It seems something is wrong on the server part. Can you post any additional output from server??

On server I have a servlet which receives user and passcode in JSON format and returns validation result in json format back.

Comment: the server returns this: 03-07 04:48:46.933: D/Post execute:(1634): In the post-execute method: array(2) {
03-07 04:48:46.933: D/Post execute:(1634):   ["login"]=>
03-07 04:48:46.933: D/Post execute:(1634):   string(24) "alogin_string"
03-07 04:48:46.933: D/Post execute:(1634):   ["password"]=>
03-07 04:48:46.933: D/Post execute:(1634):   string(7) "password"
03-07 04:48:46.933: D/Post execute:(1634): }

Comment: this is printed when the server is called?? can you check what is returned by server??

Comment: the server just prints yes or no for logged in or not :)

Comment: Is the server accessible from internet so that I can call the service and check the data?? Or can you call the service from your browser like http://yourserver/?login=usermame&password=password and see what browser is printing (if it supports GET also)

Comment: yes, the server is http://www.problemio.com/auth/mobile_login.php also I think I am realizing what the issue is. The JSON gets returned with the parameters sent along with the returned value from the server. Is there a way to decouple the two in the Android code?

Comment: I checked the url and I am getting HTML output and it does return what you send as user and password in the query string. I think it is set like that only. You may need to check the server code.

Comment: thats interesting. That server code just has php echo statements right now. How are you able to test what it returns? Just by hitting it from the browser?

Comment: yes that is the simplest way to test as browser output is nearly actual output and you can check return type and many other things directly (if you use good browser :) )

Comment: can you assign the bounty as well??

Comment: StackOverflow says I can only award the bounty after 22 more hours. I'll do it then.  Thanks. Btw, would you know why all that output happens on the server? I just print one string and all that stuff gets output..I am not sure why.

Comment: actually it seems to me that the received array is getting printed. Although i am not a php developer but (based on this http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) check for the print() and try to remove or replace it with log function

Comment: it prints `no_such_user` at the end of array print for me which might be the actual response you are looking for

Comment: yes, omg I had a var_dump function in there that I just wasn't noticing because I was searching for echo and print statements....omg duh me - thank you for your help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're sending the username and password both as URL-encoded parameters `http://.../?username=abc&password=test` and as HTTP request headers. 
Check the documentation of your service to see where the username and password is expected.
Could it be that you service uses HTTP Basic authentication? If so, take a look at the Android documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html, under HTTP Authentication.

PS: remember to disconnect() your connection after use so the resources can be released.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to work with the `HTTPClient` a possible scenario would be like that:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(yoururlhere);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
respondEntity = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

This will also work with `HttpGet` just as you desire. Perhaps this will give you some clarity of what is "really" coming from the server.